# Using ant contrib HttpClientTask with url set to ant's property

Tags: url, ant, apache-httpclient-4.x, ant-contrib

I am trying to use ant's `property`, set based on some condition & passing to http task like:

if test env then

```
<property name="framed.url" value="http://url.to.check"/>
```

else if prod env then

```
<property name="framed.url" value="http://some.other.url.to.check"/>
```

I am trying to use ant-contrib httpclient task to call URL, like below

```
<taskdef name="http" classname="org.missinglink.ant.task.http.HttpClientTask">
...

<http url="${framed.url}"
...
```

but it is giving below error.

```
org.missinglink.http.exception.InvalidUriException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 1: org.missinglink.http.exception.InvalidUriException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 1: ${framed.url}
```

How to esacpe / pass ant `property` to `url` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked, after creating a macrodef &  making macro-call within if-else evaluation by passing the url.